# How to find unique values in jagged array

Tags: c#, linq, arrays, jagged-arrays

I would like to know how I can count the number of unique values in a jagged array.

My domain object contains a string property that has space delimitered values.

```
class MyObject
{
    string MyProperty; //e.g = "v1 v2 v3"
}
```

Given a **list** of **MyObject**'s how can I determine the number of unique values?

The following linq code returns an array of jagged array values. A solution would be to store a temporary single array of items, looped through each jagged array and if values do not exist, to add them. Then a simple count would return the unique number of values. However, was wondering if there was a *nicer* solution.

```
db.MyObjects.Where(t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.MyProperty))
    .Select(t => t.Categories.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToArray()
```

Below is a more readable example:

```
array[0] = { "v1", "v2", "v3" }
array[1] = { "v1" }
array[2] = { "v4", "v2" }
array[3] = { "v1", "v5" }
```

From all values the unique items are **v1**, **v2**, **v3**, **v4**, **v5**.

The total number of unique items is **5**.

Is there a solution, possibly using linq, that returns either only the unique values or returns the number of unique values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, with LINQ this is quite simple. First use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) to flatten the jagged array into an `IEnumerable<string>` containing all values and then call [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) to select only unique values:

```
IEnumerable<string> uniqueValues = array.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();
```

If you want to count them then use [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> uniqueValues = array.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();
int uniqueCount = uniqueValues.Count();
```

Answer (score 5):

A query expression method is

```
var query = (from arr in array
             from value in arr
             select value).Distinct();
```

Comment: Just an FYI for readers...this answer and Mark Byers answer are effectively the same thing with different syntax. The fundamental answer is "Select Many". :)